# In R, execute the (called) function when needed in main R function

Tags: r

In R programming, I created & called some R functions in a internal R script, but I need them to be executed when that function called in another main R script which is also called in internal R script.
 I used `sapply, list.files(path, pattern)` for R functions & main R script.
 For example, in `fruit.R`
script (internal R script), I called the R functions like `apple.R`, `banana.R` using `list.files` from the `frt` folder & `sapply` them in this `fruit.R` script as `apple <- apple (x,y)` and `banana <- fruit (a,b)`. At the same time, I called the `garden.R` script (main script) also in this `fruit.R` script as garden (apple, banana) and used sapply, but I need the apple, banana functions has to be executed in `garden.R` script only when they get called in the garden program.

Please help me out.

Comment: what is a internal R script?

Answer (score 0):

In your main R script file write `Source("Apple.R")` and it will make Apple.R a global function.  If you have troubles with "error no such directory or file".  Check using `getwd()` and set it using `setwd` otherwise set the working directory by going to more button over on the right side of the window (assuming you are using RStudio) and click to see more option.  One will say set working directory, so click on that, but make sure you are in the folder that you want to be. See pic below.[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, One more quick question,
I wrote an function as x<- function (a,b), I want to read this arguments & I have to pass only them from another file as x(a,b).
I hope this is something of reverse way.

Comment: Never tried it, could work as long as the values are returned using return in the function i.e. something like return a, b. Again that seems more like a python thing.

Comment: Mate, you need to press the Ask Question and write these as new questions so other users can help you.  I do not want to have to individually answer each question you have about R.